# Unity collision gameObject not disappearing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm using this code for when my 'planets' collide with my player:

```
void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "enemyPlanet") {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

I want the player to disappear when its collided with, but at the minute its just being moved around by the planets. How do I make it disappear?

Comment: It's OnCollisionEnter2D with a capital "O"